# Sentence converter not working in the presence of new line

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user for two file names. The first file will be opened for input and the second file will be opened for output. (It will be assumed that the first file contains sentences that end with a period.) The program will **read the contents of the first file and change all the letters to lowercase except the first letter of each sentence, which should be made uppercase. The revised contents should be stored in the second file.**

I'm able to get the code to work but it outputs with a large break between lines:

**MY INPUT:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYGwT.jpg

Here's the text for input.txt

```
c++ is a "High-Level Programming Language" developed by Bjarne Stroustrup at Bell Labs. 
it helps in optimizing resources AND supports multiplayer options with networking. 
google's homepage includes a button labeled I'm Feeling Lucky. 
When a user types in a search AND clicks on the button the user will be taken directly to the first search result, bypassing the search engine results page.
```

You'll notice the unnecessary spaces between lines in output.txt. I have no clue why it outputs like that.

I've tried to mess around with the while loop I have but I can't seem to debug this issue

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch;
    string inputNAME, outputNAME;
    string line;

    cout << "Please enter the filename for INPUT file: ";
    cin >> inputNAME;

    cout << "Please enter the filename for OUTPUT file: ";
    cin >> outputNAME;

    fstream inFile, outFile;
```

My code works when "input.txt" has no breaks between sentences as in each sentence is not separated.
However, when there are breaks between the sentences it no longer converts properly.

**The end goal is to get my output file to look like this:** (notice how there are no breaks between converted sentences)

Comment: Remove this `inFile.get(ch);` from the while loop and try. Already the string[0] will do the actual conversion, extracting a char from the file will change the file index.

Comment: That didn't do the trick. I was able to fix the converting issue (now each sentence starts will a capitalized letter). However, there are still these odd breaks between sentences that I can't seem to get rid of. Any thoughts?

Comment: `string string;` is a very dangerous thing to do. After this, `string` is no longer a type, it's a variable. This can wreck havoc if you try to make another `string` variable after this point. Also it doesn't contain any information about how `string` is going to be used.

Comment: What is the definition of "sentence"?  How many sentences are there in "The U.S.A. is a country in North America."?

Comment: For my purposes, it's a statement that ends w/ a period

Comment: @user4581301 ya you're right. I'll change it. That doesn't seem to be why I'm getting the sentence breaks though. Do you know why that's happening?

Comment: Why have you removed the contents of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getline(inFile, string, '.')
```

will read all text up to the first `'.'`. Given the input, `string` will contain

```
c++ is a "High-Level Programming Language" developed by Bjarne Stroustrup at Bell Labs
```

and

```
 
it helps in optimizing resources AND supports multiplayer options with networking. 
google's homepage includes a button labeled I'm Feeling Lucky. 
When a user types in a search AND clicks on the button the user will be taken directly to the first search result, bypassing the search engine results page.
```

will remain in the stream. Note the end of line that begins the data left in the stream. This is part of your bug.

`string` will be written to the file along with a `'.'` and an end of line.

The next call to `getline` will read

```
 
it helps in optimizing resources AND supports multiplayer options with networking.
```

into `string`. See the end of line character? It's going to be writen to the file. Now you have TWO end of lines. Oops.

Solution:

Don't manually add the end of line. Change

```
outFile << line << "." << endl;
```

to

```
outFile << line << ".";
```

Manually add a `flush` if you feel you need to complete the `endl`.

Comment: I replaced outFile << line << "." << endl; with outFile << line << "."; but the extra space between sentences is still there. Here's my result: https://imgur.com/a/YpVgXf3 the change didn't seem to remove the extra breaks

Comment: @Dwight Take a look at the output file.That's the only part I suggested correcting. If you want the console to have the same output, you will have to make the same modification to `cout << string << "." << endl;`.

Comment: Code works for me, I'm just having trouble getting it to display in output.txt (it only displays in my terminal window for some reason). Would you mind running it to see if it correctly displays to output.txt?

Comment: @Dwight before posting the answer I ran your code minus the `endl` I suggested removing and got a file that matches the one in your image. Literally the only change your code requires to get your expected is to remove two `endl`s, so if you're running a hybrid off my solution and secpur's, weird smurf may happen and you've learned a useful lesson: back up your code before debugging so you can A) follow multiple threads B) easily go backward if the fix doesn't fix and C) have something to compare against to verify the fix worked.

Comment: That said, your expected might not be what you want. The code de-capitalizes "Bjarne Stroustrup". You may need a much smarter parser.

Comment: cool, I got it to work now after removing the endl and being left w/: cout << line << "." ; and outFile << line << "." ; Thanks for the help!

Comment: ya that's what I want - the code should de-capitalize everything except the first word. So when you ran it (obviously w/o the endl, everything was written to output.txt)?

Answer (score 1):

Extract entire line from file first and then in the next loop, parse for the delimiter '.', like so

```
while (getline(inFile, string))
{
    stringstream sstream{ string };
    while (getline(sstream, string, '.')) {

        transform(string.begin(), string.end(), string.begin(), ::tolower);

        int i = 0;
        bool contains_alpha
            = std::find_if(string.begin(), string.end(), [&i](char c) { i++; return std::isalpha(c); }) != string.end();

        if (!contains_alpha) continue;
        string[i - 1] = toupper(string[i - 1]);

        cout << string << ".";
        outFile << string << ".";
    }
    cout << endl;
    outFile << endl;
}
```

Comment: One thing that did happen was that I'm getting an extra period in my output? Do you know why that is the case? Here's the problem: https://imgur.com/a/g7LqGDc you'll notice that each sentence now has 2 periods.